# Timeout issue making system call in Ruby on Windows XP

Tags: ruby, windows, shellexecute

The following code

```
require 'timeout'

begin
  timeout(20) do              # Line 4
    result = `hostname`
  end                         # Line 6
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Timeout"
  exit
end

puts "Result:" + result       # Line 12
```

throws the error

> *issue.rb:12:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`result' for
>   main:Object (NameError)*

but if I comment out the timeout element (lines 4 and 6), it works fine.  I have tried using IO.popen, IO.select etc but none of this helps.  I've used this timeout technique in many other areas and it worked fine.

It doesn't appear to be related to the timeout value as I have experimented with much larger and smaller values.

Am using Ruby 1.92 on Windows XP.  Any help much appreciated.

p.s. My original problem was not running "hostname" but a more complex SQL Server batch job.  As a bonus point, would a long running system task that exceeded the timeout be automatically killed?  I have read lots of posts about the timeout library not honouring timeouts when busy running system tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` variable is being defined inside the timeout block, so it's not visible in the outer scope. You should initialize it before:

```
result = nil 
begin
  timeout(20) do              # Line 4
    result = `hostname`
  end                         # Line 6
rescue Timeout::Error
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix.  Been bugging me all morning.